# Proof that uniform topology on $R^J$ is coarser than the box topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was reading Munkres "Topology" and in metric topology section I've encountered a proof on why uniform topology on $ R^J$ is coarser than box topology. The argument goes like this :
If $B$ is an $\epsilon$-ball centered at $x$, then the box neighborhood
$$
\prod (x_\alpha - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon , x_\alpha + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon)
$$
is contained in $B$. It was just unclear to me why did the author choose $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$ and not any other multiplier. Can it also be $\frac{7}{8}\epsilon$ or any number $\gamma\epsilon$ where $|\gamma|<1$?

Comment: $$\large \left(x_\alpha + \frac12\varepsilon\right) - \left(x_\alpha - \frac12\varepsilon\right) = \varepsilon $$

Comment: Yeah, and what are you implying with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for any $\delta\in(0,\epsilon)$ you get $$\prod_\alpha(x_\alpha-\delta,x_\alpha+\delta)\subseteq B\;.$$ A common error is to try to use $\delta=\epsilon$ (or in your terms $\gamma=1$), but the resulting open box contains points at distance $epsilon$ from $x$: it’s contained in the closed ball of radius $\epsilon$, but not in $B$.